# Calculating Pi with Android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, numerical-methods, memory-optimization

I'm kind of new to Java but I am writing an Android app. Right now I'm working on an async task to calculate Pi but when I run it the memory usage increases alarmingly (+5MB per second). This one piece of code may need to run thousands of times so it is important that it be very optimized.

```
protected BigDecimal doInBackground(Object... params) {
        digits = (int)params[0];
        piView = (TextView)params[1];
        boolean add = true;
        BigDecimal pi = new BigDecimal(0.0);
        for(int i=1; pi.setScale(digits, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN).equals(realPi) == false; i++){
            if(add){
                pi = pi.add(new BigDecimal(4.0 / (-1 + (i*2))));
                add = false;
            }
            else {
                pi = pi.subtract(new BigDecimal(4.0 / (-1 + (i*2))));
                add = true;
            }
        }
        return pi;
    }
```

This one piece of code may need to run thousands of times so it is important that it be very optimized.

Comment: Also, does your code actually computes pi, or is it stuck eating up memory?

Comment: It will compute pi given enough time (also thanks I haven't used code review before, i'll edit the title)

Comment: I don't know what is causing the memory leak, but the if loop would probably be clearer as a while, since the test condition doesn't use "i".

Comment: I think for works fine because I'd have to make a count variable anyway

Comment: Why not use double primitive type all the way?

Comment: As a simple project I'm trying to make an app that lets you calculate pi on your phone and that lets you set the number of digits. (hence a double would be either too small or too big)

Comment: Ok, but you already limit yourself to the capabilities of double by instantiating your BigDecimal instances based on doubles : `new BigDecimal(4.0 / (-1 + (i*2)))`

Comment: Oh wow! Your right, I'll have to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>     boolean add = true;
>     for(int i=1; pi.setScale(digits, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN).equals(realPi) == false; i++){
>         if(add){
>             pi = pi.add(new BigDecimal(4.0 / (-1 + (i*2))));
>             add = false;
>         }
>         else {
>             pi = pi.subtract(new BigDecimal(4.0 / (-1 + (i*2))));
>             add = true;
>         }
>     }
> ```

You don't need an `add` variable.  Consider

```
    int i = 1;
    while (!pi.setScale(scale, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN).equals(realPi)) {
        pi = pi.add(new BigDecimal(4.0 / i));
        i += 2;
        pi = pi.subtract(new BigDecimal(4.0 / i));
        i += 2;
    }
```

This may do one extra `subtract` operation, but it does half as many `equals` operations.  And it doesn't waste time on setting and checking a variable just to alternate between two operations.

We don't need the `(-1 + (i*2))` part.  If we increment by 2 instead of 1, we get the same stream of values with strictly less math.  1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, ...

I changed the `== false` to the more idiomatic `!`.

I also changed `digits` to `scale` as I had trouble reading the original.

`BigDecimal` gives precise results, not quick results.  It is quite possible that you are hitting real limits of the format.  It's unclear at the moment why you are calculating \$\pi\$.  With more context, we might be able to give more help.

Comment: While this is a much neater and concise way of writing the code it does not in fact slow the memory consumption at all

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @mdfst13's excellent answer.

I see nothing that could leak memory. However you are allocating a lot of new `BigDecimal` objects in a tight loop and then throwing them away. These must sooner or later be garbage collected by the VM. The GC sees that it has plenty of memory available in the system and is thus postponing its work of cleaning up so that your program can run quicker, it will clean up the memory when it feels that there is a need to do so.

In other words, things are working as normal. Do not be alarmed by the memory usage.

Comment: While I do think it might be creating the new BigDecimals each time  that is creating the problem the Garbage collector is not doing its job because the allocated memory increases until the app crashes.